# Best location for a query, or shortcode generator on the Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm still new to Wordpress, so I'm still not sure if this is possible.

I made a widget with a bunch of different options, and I also made a shortcode that can create said widget. I also added a shortcode generator to the widget editing page but this is too impractical since it forces people to create a widget, save the widget to generate the shortcode, copy the shortcode, and then delete the original widget.

What I want is to create a page somewhere in the Wordpress dashboard, where administrators can easily create a shortcode using a Javascript app. I assume that this is already a thing.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely possible! WordPress Plugin docs (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) are extensive and contain all the info you need. Give it a try and if you get stuck post your attempted code and you will get pointed help.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Thanks, cool name by the way.